# How can I loop through a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to achieve not repeat the code:

Here's my html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center" id="show">
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/baratheon.png" alt="baratheon" id="17">
        </div>
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/lannister.jpg" alt="lannister" id="229">
        </div>
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/stark.jpg" alt="stark" id="362">
        </div>
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/targaryen.jpg" alt="targaryen" id="378">
        </div>

        <div class="container bg-light text-left" id="house_details">
            <h3>House Details</h3>
            <p id="house_name"> </p>
            <p id="house_words"> </p>
            <p id="house_title"> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/GoT/got.js"></script>
</body>
```

and here's my javascript code:

```
$('#house_details').hide();

document.getElementById('17').addEventListener('click', displayInfo);

function displayInfo() {
    $('#house_details').toggle();

    let house_name = document.getElementById('house_name');
    let house_words = document.getElementById('house_words');
    let house_title = document.getElementById('house_title');

    fetch('https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/17/')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(({ name, words, titles }) => {
            house_name.textContent = `Name: ${name}`;
            house_words.textContent = `Words: ${words}`;
            house_title.textContent = `Words: ${titles}`;
        });
}

document.getElementById('229').addEventListener('click', displayInfo);

function displayInfo() {
    $('#house_details').toggle();

    let house_name = document.getElementById('house_name');
    let house_words = document.getElementById('house_words');
    let house_title = document.getElementById('house_title');

    fetch('https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/229/')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(({ name, words, titles }) => {
            house_name.textContent = `Name: ${name}`;
            house_words.textContent = `Words: ${words}`;
            house_title.textContent = `Words: ${titles}`;
        });
}
```

How can I achieve not repeat the code 4 times but still get the image id and the fetch id to show? I tried to loop but the result is not quite right!

I appreciate every answers! Thank you

Comment: `fetch('https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/' + this.id + '/')`

Comment: let me understand your project first .When i click on the image tag with the id 17 or 229.You want to run displayinfo() and  display the container with the id of 'house_details'? is it?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let divArr = [17, 229, 362, 378];
for (var i=0; i<divArr.lendth(); i++){
   document.getElementById(divArr[i]).addEventListener('click', displayInfo(divArr[i]);
}
function displayInfo(id) {
  $('#house_details').show();

  let house_name = document.getElementById('house_name');
  let house_words = document.getElementById('house_words');
  let house_title = document.getElementById('house_title');
 fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/${id}/`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({
      name,
      words,
      titles
    }) => {
      house_name.textContent = `Name: ${name}`;
      house_words.textContent = `Words: ${words}`;
      house_title.textContent = `Words: ${titles}`;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Lain's comment implies, just pull the id from the target of the click event and use it as a variable in the function, for example:

```js
$('#house_details').hide();

let ids = [17, 229, 362, 378];
for (let i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById(ids[i]).addEventListener('click', displayInfo);
}


function displayInfo() {
  $('#house_details').show();

  let house_name = document.getElementById('house_name');
  let house_words = document.getElementById('house_words');
  let house_title = document.getElementById('house_title');

  fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/${this.id}/`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({
      name,
      words,
      titles
    }) => {
      house_name.textContent = `Name: ${name}`;
      house_words.textContent = `Words: ${words}`;
      house_title.textContent = `Words: ${titles}`;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center" id="show">
    <div class="card d-inline-block ">
      <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/baratheon.png" alt="baratheon" id="17">
    </div>
    <div class="card d-inline-block ">
      <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/lannister.jpg" alt="lannister" id="229">
    </div>
    <div class="card d-inline-block ">
      <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/stark.jpg" alt="stark" id="362">
    </div>
    <div class="card d-inline-block ">
      <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/targaryen.jpg" alt="targaryen" id="378">
    </div>

    <div class="container bg-light text-left" id="house_details">
      <h3>House Details</h3>
      <p id="house_name"> </p>
      <p id="house_words"> </p>
      <p id="house_title"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Really appreciate your help! But Is there anyway i can loop thru those id and then just need 1 line of code for document.getElementById('17').addEventListener('click', displayInfo);

Comment: @NathanNguyen yes you can put the ids in an array and loop through it like gabibrk show's in their answer

Comment: let divArr = [ ];
for (var i = 0; i < $('img').length; i++) {
 divArr.push($('img')[i].id);
}

Comment: if i do console.log('img')[i].id it will give me all the id like array in your code but i cant get them in to document.getElementById...

Answer (score 0):

we can refactor the code

Move reusable object from your method

```
 let house_name = document.getElementById('house_name');
    let house_words = document.getElementById('house_words');
    let house_title = document.getElementById('house_title');
```

create a reusable method with a parameter

```
function displayInfo(id) {

  $('#house_details').toggle();

  fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/${id}/`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({ name, words, titles }) => {
        house_name.textContent = `Name: ${name}`;
        house_words.textContent = `Words: ${words}`;
        house_title.textContent = `Words: ${titles}`;
    });
}
```

Register your click event like below

```
   let id = 17 ;
   document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', displayInfo.bind(this,id));
   id = 229;
   document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', displayInfo.bind(this,id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you click on the image tags.You want to run displayInfo() and display the container with the id of "house_details".
For example's sake you have showed us only the code for 2 image tags?.
With your code ,there is no of adding event listener to each image tag.

And i would suggest not to use vanilla javascript and jQuery together.
do it like this :

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center" id="show">
    <div class="card d-inline-block ">
        <img class="card-img-bottom house" src="/GoT/houseimgs/baratheon.png" alt="baratheon" id="17">
    </div>
    <div class="card d-inline-block ">
        <img class="card-img-bottom house" src="/GoT/houseimgs/lannister.jpg" alt="lannister" id="229">
    </div>
    <div class="card d-inline-block">
        <img class="card-img-bottom house" src="/GoT/houseimgs/stark.jpg" alt="stark" id="362">
    </div>
    <div class="card d-inline-block ">
        <img class="card-img-bottom house" src="/GoT/houseimgs/targaryen.jpg" alt="targaryen" id="378">
    </div>

    <div class="container bg-light text-left" id="house_details">
        <h3>House Details</h3>
        <p id="house_name"> </p>
        <p id="house_words"> </p>
        <p id="house_title"> </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/GoT/got.js"></script>
```

Add the same classes to every image tags 
and add a event listener to those in jQuery like this:

```
  $('#house_details').hide();

$(".house).click(displayInfo)

function displayInfo() {
    $('#house_details').toggle();

    let house_name = $('#house_name');
    let house_words =$('#house_words');
    let house_title = $('#house_title');
    let id = $(this).attr("id");  //get id of whichever image tag you  click on

    fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/${id}/`) //use the id here
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(({ name, words, titles }) => {
            house_name.textContent = `Name: ${name}`;
            house_words.textContent = `Words: ${words}`;
            house_title.textContent = `Words: ${titles}`;
        });
}
```

Do not hard code a array which contains all your id's which u want to loop through.Just take the id of the image tag which you click on following the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-val to pass id, for example:

```html
<div class="card d-inline-block ">
    <img data-id="17" class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/baratheon.png" alt="baratheon">
</div>
```

And add listener to all card image by className

```js
document.getElementById('card-img-bottom').addEventListener('click', displayInfo);
```

Full code list below

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center" id="show">
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/baratheon.png" alt="baratheon" data-id="17">
        </div>
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/lannister.jpg" alt="lannister" data-id="229">
        </div>
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/stark.jpg" alt="stark" data-id="362">
        </div>
        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
            <img class="card-img-bottom" src="/GoT/houseimgs/targaryen.jpg" alt="targaryen" data-id="378">
        </div>

        <div class="container bg-light text-left" id="house_details">
            <h3>House Details</h3>
            <p id="house_name"> </p>
            <p id="house_words"> </p>
            <p id="house_title"> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/GoT/got.js"></script>
</body>
```

js code

```js
    const cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card-img-bottom');

    Array.from(cards).forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener('click', displayInfo);
    });

    function displayInfo() {
      $('#house_details').toggle();

      let house_name = document.getElementById('house_name');
      let house_words = document.getElementById('house_words');
      let house_title = document.getElementById('house_title');

      const id = this.dataset.id;
      fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/${id}/`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(({ name, words, titles }) => {
          house_name.textContent = `Name: ${name}`;
          house_words.textContent = `Words: ${words}`;
          house_title.textContent = `Words: ${titles}`;
        });
    }
```